# Track sign-ups with facebook pixel on click (JS/JQUERY code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to track sign-ups on website, I've installed the Facebook pixel by putting it in the head section.

I want to fire:

```
fbq('track', 'Lead');
```

When someone clicks the button (which is an input element with the ID "#es_txt_button_pg")

I've added this script to my website:

```
$("#es_txt_button_pg").click(fbq('track', 'Lead'));
```

Should this code work?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a function to the click. E.g.

```
$("#es_txt_button_pg").click(function(){fbq('track', 'Lead');});
```

Comment: Thank you that was what I was thinking.

Comment: But how do you add the lately needed parameters `currency` and `value` here?